# docker-compose mysql init sql is not executed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to set up a mysql docker container and execute init sql script. Unfortunately the sql script is not executed. What am I doing wrong?

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: 'api'
    build: './api'
  ports:
    - target: 8080
      published: 8888
      protocol: tcp
      mode: host
  volumes:
    - './api:/go/src/app'
  depends_on:
    - 'mysql'
 mysql:
  image: 'mysql:latest'
  container_name: 'mysql'
  volumes:
    - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    - ./database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql:ro
  restart: always
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: test
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    MYSQL_DATABASE: test
  ports:
    - '3306:3306'
volumes:
  db_data:
```

I execute file with `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: The `db_data` folder probably has data from a previous run of the container. Try cleaning up the containers, removing the data folder and start again

Comment: Thank you! Deleting db_data folder solved it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Many containerized applications, especially stateful ones, have a way of running `init` scripts (like the sql scripts here) **and** they are supposed to run only *once*.

And since they are stateful, the volumes are a source of truth for the containers on whether to run the `init` scripts or not on container restart.

Like in your case, deleting the folder used for bind mount or using a new named volume should re-run any `init` scripts present.

Comment: How do you find out what the bind mount folder is?

Comment: In most cases it is the folder which is mounted to `/var/lib/mysql`. This is the default for mysql and can be changed (mounted) in `mysql.cnf` file. In the example above the bind is `./db_data`.

Answer (score 26):

The `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder will only be run once while the container is created (instantiated) so you actually have to do a `docker-compose down -v` to re-activate this for the next run.

If you want to be able to add sql files at any moment you can look here at a specialized MySql docker image... http://ivo2u.nl/o4

Update for M1 arch:
Here an almost drop-in replacement in MariaDB: http://ivo2u.nl/V1

Comment: "docker compose down -v" helped me deleting the volumes

Answer (score 1):

These scripts run when you create the container, not every time you start it.

You can `docker-compose up --force-recreate mysql` to force those scripts to re-run.

Additionally, if you have a volume like this `./db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw`, then you also need to remove `./db_data` before recreating the container.

I'm not a docker expert, but this worked for me.